# vector Database sizing

Tags: vector-database

I am trying to estimate for requesting Redis Vector database. I am not aware of any standard basis on how to calculate the size and publish the requirements to the infrastructure to provision a Redis Vector database. Please share any approach on how to approach sizing and share some numbers for provisioning a Redis vector database.

I am going to use the vector database for capturing the embeddings using the embed-models and store them into a vector database. The vector database will be used by the LLM application to retrieve the embeddings based on the query search and then used by LLM to generate text responses.

text data (Average) = 10000 tokens processed / day.

Assuming embeddings / token = 2kb.

Projected volume of data processed / day = 2kb * 10000 = 20MB => 600MB per month.

Is it fair to state, as per my above estimate, that I will need a vector DB that can store ~ 1 GB per month for running LLM apps using the vector DB with this configuration using Langchain? Please advise If I am missing something here.